# Add Launcher Icon in React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I want to add launcher icons to my React Native app without using Android studio and XCode. I am using Expo. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did your check it out the expo documentation about it?

- [Expo - App Icons](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/app-icons.html)
- [Expo - Configuration: Icon](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/configuration.html#icon)

Comment: Actually I did not find in documentation about it. Thanks!